# Odoo: How to set a dynamic domain to a many2many field

Tags: python, odoo

I want to change the retrieved set of values of a many2many field according to a many2one field onchange function, it worked well with another many2one field, but doesn't seem to filter the outcome on a many2many field
my code is as follows

```
class CustomPurchase(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.purchase'
    _description = 'Purchase Record'

    supplier_id = fields.Many2one('custom.supplier', string='Supplier', required=True)
    product_ids = fields.Many2many('custom.supply.line', string='Purchase Lines', required=True)

    @api.onchange('supplier_id')
    def onchange_supplier(self):
        selected_lines = []
        if self.supplier_id:
            for rec in self:
                selected_lines = rec.env['custom.supply.line'].search([('supplier_id', '=', rec.supplier_id.id)])
                domain = {'product_ids': [('id', '=', selected_lines.id)]}
            return {'domain': domain, 'value': {'selected_lines': []}}
```

Expected behavior is to have just the items related to the supplier_id many2one field

Produced behavior is all the items are retrieved

Edit:
I've noticed that i when i remove widget="section_and_note_one2many" the domain works perfectly, yet the tree view can't be edited within the same form, even with editable="bottom"

Answer (score 1):

You can add check using supplier field directly inside domain.

Code:

```
    @api.onchange('supplier_id')
    def onchange_supplier(self):
        domain = {'product_ids': []}
        for rec in self:
            if rec.supplier_id:
                domain = {'product_ids': [('supplier_id', '=', rec.supplier_id.id)]}
        return {'domain': domain}
```

**UPDATE:** 
Try to implement this as same as in `/addons/mrp/models/mrp_bom.py` on `attribute_value_ids`. [Version:12]

Comment: thank you for your reply, but my problem isn't with the supplier field check,  need to do is change the retrieved set of values based on the change of another field, it's not working either on xml or in python and my guess is it's a many2many related problem, because the same code works if i change the many2many to many2one field

Comment: which version are you using? on versions 12, 13 domain working properly on many2many fields.

Comment: using odoo 12.0